# I want to improve my react native mobile applications design and css

Tags: css, react-native, design-patterns, react-native-stylesheet

How do I improve my CSS styling for react native to design mobile apps?

Can someone recommend courses, references or documents? anything will help

Comment: you can only use lib or css in react native to make your app attractive

Comment: what is lib? Yeah I want to improve my CSS skills any idea how?

Comment: https://reactnativeelements.com/

Comment: you can add your css in code like this way<Text style={{color:"red:}}>hello</Text>

Comment: bruh, its better when you do it like this

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  textStyle: { fontSize: 14, color: 'white },  

  buttonView: { flex:1, etc..}
})

helps keep the code cleaner and more readable, also import the StyleSheet component from 'react-native' and for the const "styles" you can rename it to whichever you like same for textStyle or buttonConainer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am currently following this course on Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/react-native-the-practical-guide/ It's pretty styling intensive (although I am only 25% of the way through), it's between 10 and 20 bucks if you have a discount (never pay full price for Udemy courses, right now they have a discount until the 5th). It's for people who DO know React, but DON'T know react-native.
The first thing I learned was that react native doesn't use css for styling, but the component StyleSheet which is inspired by css.

Comment: yeah I took this course and its super helpful mate! couldn't agree more on the discount! I completely forgot the stylesheet component and kept on searching for css lol. I will update the comments if I find anything helpful

Comment: also hit me up if you need anything in the course ;)